# whats the exception here?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, hive

**HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /serverside.jsp at line 34**

type Exception report

**message An exception occurred processing JSP page /serverside.jsp at line 34**

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /serverside.jsp at line 34

```
31: </head>
32: <body>
33: <%
34: Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/nikhildb","","");
35: Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
36: String country_name = request.getParameter("country_name");
37: ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select * from population where country_name ='"+country_name+"'");

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.sendBase(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/thrift/TBase;)V
   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
org.apache.jsp.serverside_jsp._jspService(serverside_jsp.java:401)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.sendBase(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/thrift/TBase;)V
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.send_execute(ThriftHive.java:110)
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.execute(ThriftHive.java:102)
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:192)
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:132)
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.configureConnection(HiveConnection.java:133)
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:122)
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:106)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    org.apache.jsp.serverside_jsp._jspService(serverside_jsp.java:119)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 logs.

Am a bit confused for hiveserver1 and hiveserver2.Should i anything more than       **hive --service hiveserver**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HIVE JDBC ThriftHive$Client.sendBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739020/hive-jdbc-thrifthiveclient-sendbase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoSuchMethod exceptions are often times caused by using an older version of a library.  Please verify your dependencies.

Similar Question: [HIVE JDBC ThriftHive$Client.sendBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739020/hive-jdbc-thrifthiveclient-sendbase)